# how to overlay android screen using kivy or kivyMD?

Tags: python, android, kivy, kivymd

I want to use SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW permission to "Draw on top" android screen using python. it is used in a lot of apps but i don't know if kivy or any other python repository supports it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```py
from android.permissions import request_permissions, Permission
request_permissions([Permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW])
```

the above code to your main python script and below one to buildozer file

```py
android.permissions = SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW
```